# Django: userena edit profile forbidden

Tags: python, django, user-profile

I've installed `django-userena` to manage user profiles and everything works fine except new registered users unable to edit/update their profiles and face just blank screen.

If I make the user a superuser then it can change/update profile.

Found that `profile_edit` view in `django-userena` decorated with `@permission_required_or_403('change_profile', (get_profile_model(), 'user__username', 'username'))`

Obviously need to add `post_save` signal to add necessary permission and nevertheless I was wondering if there any settings like `USERENA_ALLOW_UPDATE_PROFILE` can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally digging around `django-userena` and `django-guardian` sources I present my output of this little research, so if you want the users to be able to edit their profile you can use the following code

### User post save signal which adds 'change_profile' permission to new user objects

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='user.created')
def user_created(sender, instance, created, raw, using, **kwargs):
  """ Adds 'change_profile' permission to created user objects """
  if created:
    from guardian.shortcuts import assign
    assign('change_profile', instance, instance.get_profile())
```

Answer (score 1):

For existing users, Just issue this command and the page will be working:

```
python manage.py check_permissions
```